# Confusion Matrix Value error, y_test is not equal to y_train

Tags: python, matrix

I've been trying to run a confusion matrix on a Logistic Regression result, i have splited the data so i have size 8 for y_test and 67 for y_train and i can't print the matrix. I know that they have to be the same size but i can't find a way to to that. ERROR MSG: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [8, 67]`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[["Age"]], df.Spending_Cat, test_size=0.1)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model=LogisticRegression()

model.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(model.predict(x_test))
print(model.score(x_test, y_test))
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_train))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion matrix takes as inputs y_true (the correct target values) and y_pred (Estimated targets as returned by a classifier). In this case y_true and y_pred would have for sure the same size, but you are trying to run it using both the predictions from the test and from the train, which doesn't make sense besides not working since they have different size.